# Bootstrap modal and jQuery: form inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, multipartform-data

I'm using form inside a modal window in my application which uses Bootstrap. 
Form looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="my_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="my_form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="my_file">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="my_text" id="my_text" class="form-control select-resource-form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="my_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-send">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I'm trying to send form data of this form, both file and text fields are empty at the recieveing part, and following commands in console also confirm that the form is empty:

[when I use modal fade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BszYe.png)

If I replace the `modal fade` attribute in the root tag,for example, with `modal-body`, everything works just fine, but I need a modal window for my purposes, which shows up, sends the response and closes. 
[when I use modal-body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQMuX.png)

Would appreciate any ideas/workarounds about this

UPDATE:
ajax for the query is:

```
let form = $("#my_form").get(0);
$.ajax({
        url: "some/url/Im/sending/data/to",
        method: "POST",
        data: new FormData(form),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see how you are sending the form (ajax).

Comment: Updated the question with this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. When the modal window was instantiated, the page also instantiated a second one with class `in`. So I changed the selector for the window to the following and everything worked
`"#my_modal.in #my_form"`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it appears that the structure of your modal is missing some items. It should look something like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" ...
   <div class="modal-dialog" ...
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
              your form
```

Also, I believe `form-group`'s are only supposed to be inside `form`s.

Comment: `type="submit"` will reload the page, thus resetting the form.

Comment: I assumed that the OP wanted to post/submit the data.

Comment: I suppose my wording could have been better. But changing `type="button"` to `type="submit"` will change the dynamic of the page. OP said it does submit when they target a different element so I don't believe that's part of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @EternalHour I believe you're correct. I will remove that part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems only to change the appearence of the modal, the data sent is still empty